# How to run a bigQuery SQL query in command line?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using the BigQuery to execute some queries for data obtained from Open targes.
I have the following query :

```
WITH
  SNP_info AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier
  FROM
  `386212.dataset_1.SNPs`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SNP_info
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier,
*
 FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.open_targets_genetics.variants`) variants
ON
  SNP_info.identifier = variants.identifier
```

I was wondering how can i write this to execute it in command line ? Is it possible through Python SDK or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the query using cli, use bq cli

```
bq query --format=prettyjson --use_legacy_sql=false \
'WITH
  SNP_info AS (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier
  FROM
  `386212.dataset_1.SNPs`)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SNP_info
JOIN (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(rs_id AS string)) AS identifier,
*
 FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.open_targets_genetics.variants`) variants
ON
  SNP_info.identifier = variants.identifier' > output.json
```

Comment: And how can i download or view the result? LEts say if i want to download the result of this query in JSON?

Comment: I have updated the response above, basically redirecting to > output.json at the end

Comment: How can we make it in Python like the next answer?

Comment: you could do SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(identifier) in the query to return you results in json format

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can call python scripts to run BQ Queries. See sample below.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery




def query_stackoverflow():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.query(
        """
        SELECT
          CONCAT(
            'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',
            CAST(id as STRING)) as url,
          view_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
        WHERE tags like '%google-bigquery%'
        ORDER BY view_count DESC
        LIMIT 10"""
    )

    results = query_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

    for row in results:
        print("{} : {} views".format(row.url, row.view_count))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    query_stackoverflow()
```

Other usage of client libraries in BigQuery is available [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries) for your reference and might be helpful.

Comment: I made it work but i can not export the output of my query in JSON in python script. How can i make the script above in python to write the output of my query in JSON ?  In the  """ """ i have my query  but the for eow in result is for your query ! How to modify this in order to get the output of my query ?